# How do I merge two subs with Private Sub Worksheet_Change on sheet, which have different triggers

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 private sub worksheet_change subs that need to be on the same sheet and can't work out how to combine them.  Very new to this whole vba game and both subs I have found on various websites.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  The 2 pieces of code are below.  One gets the time a cell changes and the other dispalys a message box when another cell changes (Have updated since first post.  Both are worksheet_change subs

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim rCell As Range
Dim rChange As Range

On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Set rChange = Intersect(Target, Range("A:A"))
If Not rChange Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each rCell In rChange
        If rCell > "" Then
            With rCell.Offset(0, 1)
                .Value = Now
                .NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
            End With
        Else
            rCell.Offset(0, 1).Clear
        End If
    Next
End If

ExitHandler:
    Set rCell = Nothing
Set rChange = Nothing
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume ExitHandler

End Sub
```

And second one is

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not (Application.Intersect(Range("AH4"), Target) Is Nothing) Then
    MsgBox "Broadcast Now!"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I am not sure to follow, there is no apparent reason to why you would want to merge these procedures as they are triggered by different events. If it is just a mater of which sheet they need to work with, just paste these codes in the sheet code you want. You'll have to give more details about your overall objective if you want more help.

Comment: Sorry, had changed the second one and not noticed should be the following as the one I originally posted does not work.  Assuming it is because it is looking at the result of a formula, will work if I manually change it

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not (Application.Intersect(Range("AH4"), Target) Is Nothing) Then
        MsgBox "Broadcast Now!"
    End If

    End Sub